# @tensorflow/tfjs-tflite won't load

Tags: tensorflow, error-handling, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

I tried to load up into a local webpage `@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite` in the following configuration:

```js
import "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs-core";
import * as tflite from "@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite";
```

as described in https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-tflite#via-npm
yet I'm getting this error when loading:
[image: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()]

### EDIT

After further testing, I'm able to load the modules via the [CDN](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-tflite#via-a-script-tag):

```html
<!-- Import @tensorflow/tfjs-core -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
<!-- Adds the CPU backend -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu"></script>
<!--
  Import @tensorflow/tfjs-tflite

  Note that we need to explicitly load dist/tf-tflite.min.js so that it can
  locate WASM module files from their default location (dist/).
-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite/dist/tf-tflite.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What version of the three packages did you have installed when using Node.js? I'm trying to get to the root of the problem.

Comment: @JenPerson I failed a [bug report](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6726) that mentions them

Comment: I saw that--thanks for filing!